# Select rows inserted within 5 seconds ago

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm trying to select rows from my database which were inserted within 5 seconds ago.

I'm currently working with this query:

```
$timerightnow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT notimessage,
                          Second(TIMEDIFF('$timerightnow',dateofreg)) AS Second1
                          FROM notitb
                          WHERE checked = 0 HAVING Second1 <= 5")){
```

But it doesn't show any results. Am I doing it correctly? Or my query is simply incorrect just from the beginning?

Comment: Try using `HAVING Second1 = 5` as `Second1` is virtual and therefore it's not created yet when applying `WHERE`

Answer (score 1):

Your query certainly has some syntax errors. In particular, your $timerightnow is a string, but it is not in the quotes, ans Second1 is an alias, and therefore cannot be used in `WHERE`, it can only be used in `HAVING`. It would help you if you can see the errors, instead of trying to debug them blindly. This will help:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Then, note, that `prepare` does not execute the query, it only prepares it. You then need to bind the parameters (in particular, I would bind the current date rather than hardcode it into the query string), and then you need to execute the query via `$stmt->execute()`. It is not clear if you are doing that, because your code is truncated, if you are not, then this will be helpful:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

See the example there where they prepare a query, bind some params, and execute it.

Finally, you might want your predicate be `Second1 <= 5` instead of `Second1 = 5`, if you want to get everything from the last 5 seconds, not just the things that happened during the second that was five seconds ago.

Comment: I've tried using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` for the `Second1`. But didn't work. And I'm aware of course with prepared statement. I know the basics of it, binding and executing. And for the `<=`, I forgot about that one. :P

Comment: I guessed you might call execute below, but it was not clear :) Anyway, most importantly, you need to know the error your query fails with. Can you try printing mysqli_error after you call execute to see why the query fails? It should fail at least because the date is not in quotes.